# What does Ctrl+2 do in the Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line

In Microsoft Windows Command Prompt, what does the command `ctrl+2` do?

I get the following output:

```
C:\Users\jallen>^@
More?
```

What is this `More?` prompt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The More? prompt is what you get after using a caret at the end of command line and allows you to continue typing a command across multiple lines.

```
C:\>dir ^
More? c:\users
```

Is the same as

```
c:\>dir c:\users
```

Can be useful in batch files to make them more readable over using really long lines.

CONTROL + 2 produces ^@ which is null. From Wikipedia

> 0 (null, NUL, \0, ^@), originally intended to be an ignored character,
>   but now used by many programming languages to mark the end of a
>   string.

On the Windows command line it functions like using a caret except it can be placed before the end of a line. Not sure if this is intended functionality or a quirk of the command processor.

```
C:\>dir ^@ A nonstandard place for a comment using CTRL-2
More? c:\users
```

Comment: tested on xp pro cmd.exe  ctrl-2 didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @barlop Press enter after using CTRL-2 to get the `More?` prompt. Tested here with Windows XP Pro on Windows 7 Pro (XP Mode).

Comment: oh i've figured out the conundrum. I am on a UK keyboard/layout. On a UK keyboard, 2 has a quote(happens to be double quote) above it.  But the key with single quote has an @ above it reached with shift. If I do ctrl+@ (so ctrl+shift+') to give ctrl-@ then it works. But it also works if I do ctrl+' then I get ^@  So, you can skip the shift. So for any keyboard it's ctrl with the key with @ on it.